# Condition (if) statement pointing to a file extension 

Tags: cocoa

Thanks for the help.

I need to tell my app.something like:

if the input QTmovie has a .whatever file extension ...

etc. etc. etc.

I'm doing something like this that recognizes input movie width:

```
if (movieSize.width == 1600){

     whatever
```

How would I code a file extension condition?

thanks.

Paul

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? Especially the "etc. etc. etc." part.

Comment: It's sort of a general question. In the example above, if the input movie/file is 1600 pixels wide, the app window resizes itself to specific dimensions. No problem getting this done. I also want to set things up in case the input file has a specific file extension. I'm just not sure how to code the if statement that would recognize this specific file extension. Make sense?

Comment: Can you show us what type of string you are using? Is it an `NSString`, `char*`, `std::string`, etc?

Comment: The width of the movie is a red herring, Paul. It isn't relevant to the name of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the full file path as an NSString, you can call pathExtension on it like this:

```
NSString *extension = [movieFilePath pathExtension];
```

Then, you'd just add another condition to the if statement, like:

```
if (movieSize.width == 1600 && [extension isEqualToString:@"mp4"]) {

    // do whatever

}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: A file may have the extension `"mp4"` however, or be `nil`. Try `extension && NSOrderedSame == [extension caseInsensitiveCompare:@"mp4"]`.

Comment: Guy's thanks. Jonathan, I'm not concerned about the movie width with this condition. I simply listed it to show how I was using the movie width attribute in that particular conditional statement example. With the new extension condition it will be proprietary and non case sensitive because the file extension will never change.  Alec, thanks.

Comment: @Paul: I didn't say anything about the width. And you might not be concerned about the extension, but the OS acts case-insensitively, so you should as well.